# Terraform showing only default workspace in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: python, jenkins, terraform, pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline I am using to perform terraform actions. The Jenkins pipeline runs python scripts to perform those actions (and some more). One of those actions is `terraform workspace select`, and the python function is this:

```
def terraform_plan(options):
    provider=get_cluster_info(options)['provider'].upper() // returns "AWS"
    workspace=get_cluster_info(options)['terraform_workspace'] // returns abc
    working_dir=f'{REPO_PATH}/{provider}/K8S' // returns "./repo_path/AWS/K8S"
    run_subprocess(f"/usr/local/bin/terraform -chdir={working_dir} workspace list")
    run_subprocess(f"/usr/local/bin/terraform -chdir={working_dir} workspace select {workspace}")
```

(NOTE: `run_subprocess` only executes the command in the parenthesis and prints some other lines).

The pipeline also runs `run_subprocess(f"/usr/local/bin/terraform -chdir={working_dir} init")` before the function above, and the init is run successfully (according to the output.

If I run the pipeline, the output says that the `abc` workspace does not exist, and the `terraform list` before that shows only the default workspace.
However, if I run `terraform workspace show` in the terminal (in the exact same directory where the pipeline runs), I get all of the workspaces as normal.

I tried running the `terraform workspace` commands in different order, made sure the init part is successful, and made sure all the files are present.

How can I fix this? Why is this even happening?

Comment: Does your pipeline run `terraform init -chdir={working_dir}`, or something comparable to it, at some point prior to running these commands? Workspaces are defined by the active backend, so if you are using a remote backend and don't activate it first then Terraform won't be able to see your workspaces.

Comment: @MartinAtkins Yes, I mentioned it in the fourth sentence. I am running the init before the `workspace select`